# Nginx, Python, Docker and Node in same server creating issue

Tags: python, node.js, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have UBUNTU 20.04 instance. i have installed NGINX and Docker and NODE JS. there is am trying to run 6 docker container. within that 6 docker container i have 2 node application and 4 python application. node js container are working fine. but issue with my python containers. when websites have 10-20 users comes online server getting slow and some api's are giving 502 bad gateway responses. all the application Database is PostgreSql. i have check the application and database server resource via netdata also. servers have not much load also.

Server Configuration

4 CPU, 8GB RAM

here is my NGINX config file sample

```
server {
server_name api.domain.com;

location / {

proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:7999;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
client_max_body_size 1000M;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the application is struggling to allocate resources from the machine. Try to monitor the machine resources to make sure that your CPU/Memory/Disk are not being over utilized.

Then, make sure to assign CPU and memory limits to the containers as mentioned here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

Comment: I have checked the server resource is idle. the server doesn't have above 10% of the load. I am not getting the issue either it is nginx config issue or something else

Comment: Have you checked it when the slowness is occurring?  If it was an nginx configuration issue, the requests will always be failing. Please check the host OS (ubuntu) resources using `top` while the slowness is happening.

Comment: yes I have checked with top and htop as well. there is no CPU using data when slowness is occurring @akathimi

Comment: mmm, this is weird, do you have any restarts in the applications? you can get that by checking the uptime in `docker ps` or by running `docker events --filter event=restart --since=60m`. Also, to check the current container resource consumption, please use `docker stats`

Comment: I ran the docker stats command and got the below output
41.5MB is the maximum network capacity? if it is then how can I increase the limit? @akathimi


`CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %        NET I/O            BLOCK I/O     PIDS`
`0.01%      93.97MiB / 5.821GiB      1.58%     21.7MB / 41.5MB   1.03MB / 0B   2`

Comment: Net I/O is the amount of data the container has sent and received over its network interface, its not like CPU %. as detailed here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/